Use the Node Export module to export nodes with images
My team and I want to use the Node Export Module to export and import nodes that include image fields between environments of our Drupal 10 site. However, when I export nodes, the image fields only contain the UID for the image and not the image itself, meaning that when importing into a different environment, the images are left blank.
In looking into this issue, I found several patches that work for older versions of the module -- in particular, I saw that there was a patch that could base64 encode and decode the images: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export/issues/570464 , which seems to achieve exactly what I want. However, these patches do not work with the latest, Drupal 10-compatible versions of the module.
Does anyone know of solutions to achieve what I want to do here (including other modules I should consider using instead of Node Export)? Thank you very much!

Try https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content

My team ended up deciding to use the Single Content Sync module instead! It works quite well for importing and exporting single items or content in bulk, including content with images.
